# How to detect EOF on DataReader in C# without executing Read()

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm familiar with using .Read() to detect the EOF

```
        using (IDataReader reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(_connectionString, "dbo.GetOrders"))
        {
            AssertOrder(reader);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return FillRecord<Order>(reader, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Due to some weird situation I got myself into, the FillRecord actually advances the reader.  So now the .Read() in the while loop actually causes this function to skip some rows -- because we are advancing twice.

I wish there was an IDataReader.EOF, but there isn't.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Fixing the weird situation is not an option?

Comment: Might also be a good idea to not pass a `DataReader` around like that.  No reason you can't grab the row data from it and pass it into `FillRecord` instead.

Comment: I like the weird situation.  It was elegant up to now.

Comment: As all shortcuts usually are. (with the inevitable "up to now" coming some time in the future).

Comment: You will have to come out of this weird situation and make sure that here is only one thing that advances the reader, otherwise be ready for way too complex design.

Comment: What does FillRecord return if its own call to Read() returns false? If it returns null you can check for that.

Comment: No need to call `.Close()`, `using` is doing that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I probably made my opinion clear in the comments... but, since you asked for "Any Thoughts"... here ya go:

Obviously a two second hack job, but you'll get the idea:

(You'd surely want to implement IDisposable (since I think IDataReader is??) etc. Probably just make the class inherit from IDataReader, and implement the class as a facade. Or get real cool and implement a transparent proxy which hijacks the Read method.

```
public class DataReaderWithEOF
{
     public bool EOF { public get; private set; }
     private IDataReader reader;

     public DataReaderWithEOF(IDataReader reader)
     {
          this.reader = reader;
     }

     public bool Read()
     {
           bool result = reader.Read();
           this.EOF = !result;
           return result;
     }
}
```

Comment: Nice.  A decorator.  I'll give that a whirl.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
using (IDataReader reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(_connectionString, "dbo.GetOrders"))
    {
         if(!reader.HasRows)
         {
              Response.Write("EOF"); // empty
         }
         while (reader.Read()) //read only registers
         {
               yield return FillRecord<Order>(reader, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
          }
          reader.Close();
       }
    }
```

every time u use a. Read () it next record. 
then do if(reader.Read()) u would already be advancing a record.

Comment: Please, add an explanation. At least, write why you think that this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Steve's solution is to call reader.Close() in FillRecord when Read() returns false.  Then you can check reader.IsClosed in your main loop.