# Is there a way to tell if a DataReader has been iterated through without calling .Read()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datareader

Let's say I return a DataReader and completely iterate through it using this code:

```
While Reader.Read
    Dim x as string = Reader.GetString("x")
End While
```

I would like to be able to determine whether or not it has been iterated through after the While loop *without* calling .Read().  The reason why is because .Read() automatically advances to the next row when it is called.  If there is a circumstance where the reader hasn't completely been iterated through, I don't want it to advance to the next row.  It seems there would be some way to tell if a reader has been fully read.

Comment: You could fill a datatable. Datareader won't let you go back.

Comment: No, there is no way to check using directly the out-of-the-box DataReader, but look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844355/how-to-detect-eof-on-datareader-in-c-sharp-without-executing-read) and how they have nicely solved the problem

Comment: Steve, I believe your answer is the correct one.  You should convert to answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Thanks, but this will be a duplicate. (please use the @ symbol before the name otherwise I will never know that you have a comment for me) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Steve in the question's comments, it looks like this is a duplicate:

[How to detect EOF on DataReader in C# without executing Read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844355/how-to-detect-eof-on-datareader-in-c-sharp-without-executing-read)

Since Steve doesn't want to put his comment at the answer, I am answering my own question with this link.  I would delete the question, but se won't let me since it has answers.  I won't want this to affect my question/answer ratio, so here we are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for: [HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx#note), which enables you to determine if the DataReader has any results reading from it.

```
if(Reader.HasRows) {}
```

Comment: Isn't the question about whether or not the reader has been completely read, not does the reader have any data?

Comment: HasRows is still true also after you have read all the data. So it is not reliable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong.

```
If there is a circumstance where the reader hasn't completely been iterated through
```

It iterates till the reader.

If you use,

```
If reader.read
//
End if
```

It reads only one time

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  In my question, I believe I said *The reason why is because .Read() automatically advances to the next row when it is called*.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your data in `Datareader` by loading it into a `DataTable` like below,

```
 Dim DtTbl As DataTable = New DataTable

 'Load Your DataReader into a Datatable
 DtTbl .Load(rdr) 

 'And Here You can itereate through Your data like below
 For Each xDataRow As DataRow In DtTbl .Rows
      MsgBox(xDataRow.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
 Next
```

[**Note**: Once you have loaded your data from `datareader` to a `datatable`, The `datareader` will get closed automatically. But at the same time you can iterate through that `datatable` many times with count any constraints.]